# Grafana/InfluxDB: Query works in panel, not in variable

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have a InfluxDB data set containing a large number of time series data from a bunch of virtual machines.

I'm trying to set up a variable to return the names of the top 10 machines with the highest CPU usage above a threshold.

The following query works in the query editor (I can get the results I want in a panel):

```
SELECT "name" FROM (SELECT TOP(usage, 10), "name" FROM (SELECT
SUM("cpu") AS usage FROM "location" WHERE ("type"=~/^$microservice$/)
AND $timeFilter AND "cpu" >= $cpuLimit GROUP BY "name"))
```

But when I try and define a new variable with this query, it errors out. For reference, `$microservice` is the name of the program selected, and `$cpuLimit` is another variable containing the threshold.

If I do:

```
SELECT "name" FROM (SELECT TOP(usage, 10), "name" FROM (SELECT
SUM("cpu") AS usage FROM "location" WHERE ("type"=~/^$microservice$/)
AND $timeFilter AND **"cpu" >= 0.5** GROUP BY "name"))
```

Then the variable works just fine. It's when I put in the `$cpuLimit` that I get the following errors:

as text:

```
Validation - InfluxDB Error: error parsing query: found \, expected ) at line 1, char 216

Templating [name_of_variable] - Error updating options: InfluxDB Error: error parsing query: found \, expected ) at line 1, char 216
```

[image: Validation and Templating Errors]

Which says that there's an unexpected character at position 216, but there's not even 216 characters in my query so I am a bit lost. Why does it work in a panel but not in a variable?

Comment: One other thing I just noticed - it errors when $cpuLimit < 1 - it seems that if there is a decimal in $cpuLimit, such as “0.5”, it throws the error.

Am I not able to use decimals in variables? Why does it work in the panel if that is the case?

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed it. I used:

```
"cpu" >= ${cpuLimit:text}
```

I found this in [the documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v7.5/variables/syntax/).